# How can I read Notepad++ file in DOS or Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I received a textfile created with Notepad++ that I'm trying to read with a Fortran 95 program on both a Mac and a PC. The read line is:

```
 read(lun,'(a)',iostat=io1) input
```

Since I don't know what the line lengths are I defined input to be 512 in length. With non-notepad++ files when the end of line is found the read "stops" and automatically advances to the next line of text. With the notepad++ file, it reads 512 characters, skipping over the carriage returns. When I open the file using the dos editor on the pc I see carriage return symbols (ASCII char 13) but there is no break between lines, they are all appended to one another.

I've tried searching for `ichar(13)` and `ichar(10)`, backspacing to the beginning of the line and trying to force an advance to the next line; reading in with `format '(a,/')'`, but haven't been able to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a pipeline type design.  The basic routine is one called getline, which gets a line of data up to the carriage return.  Inside the initialization, what you do is open the file as a binary file and read a buffer of say 1024 characters in.  Whenever getline is called, return the next lot of characters until you get to a CR.  If there aren't enough characters, move the unprocessed characters to the front and read in the remaining characters.

It is basically how compilers work - they get a stream of tokens, which, in your case is a string of characters ending with a CR, and then they process the tokens.